# How to parse Intel Hex file in .Net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there any way to parse the Intel Hex file in .Net core? Any packages like `IntelHexFormatReader`which is for .Net frameworks? Any help will be highly appreciated.

I'm using .Net core 2.1 framework.

Comment: According to the packages [home page](https://github.com/christophediericx/IntelHexFormatReader) the Nuget package is compatible with ".NET Standard 1.6". That is, try to sijmply use it with your .Net Core project.

Comment: @Christian.K You mean resusing the code without installing it?

Comment: I mean adding the [IntelHexFormatParser nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IntelHexFormatReader/) to your .NET core project.

Comment: @Christian.K Ok. I forgot they are downward compactable.